# How to map foreign key property to database in EF6 automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my database I have two tables:

**Scenario**:

```
Id
Name
Location_Id
```

**Locations**:

```
Id
Name
```

So **Scenario** has a foreign key to **Locations**.

In the code I have this:

Scenario.cs:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int LocationId { get; set; }
```

Location.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Screen> Screens { get; set; } // I do not really need this...
```

When I use it like this I get an exception:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'LocationId'

But, when I use `public virtual Location { get; set; }` in my `Scenario` class, it off course recognizes the relationship.

What I would like is that EF automatically 'maps' `LocationId` to `Location_Id`. I don't want `LocationId` in my database because other foreign keys are using the underscore: `Entity_Id`. So I don't want to configure each foreign key like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Scenario>().Property(s => s.LocationId).HasColumnName("Location_Id");
```

Comment: EF maps properties which satifies some conditions. It you don't want to follow these conditions, yo must tell EF how to map your entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [custom code first conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/custom).

Here's a convention that looks for properties ending with `Id` and at least one character preceding `Id`. The convention replaces the names by `<preceding part>` + `_` + `Id`.

```cs
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
class ForeignKeyPropertyConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmProperty>
{
    public void Apply(EdmProperty property, DbModel model)
    {
        property.Name = Regex.Replace(property.Name, "^(.*.)(Id)$", @"$1_$2");
    }
}
```

Add this convention to the model builder in `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new ForeignKeyPropertyConvention());
```

Of course, for just one foreign key property that's overkill, but in larger projects this would be a convenient way to do it.

For just this one property it would suffice to add this line:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Scenario>().Property(s => s.LocationId)
    .HasColumnName("Location_Id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the data attribute `ForeignKey`:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public Location Location { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Location")]
public int LocationId { get; set; }
```

Using the fluent API, it would look almost the same. Leave out the data attribute and include this code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Scenarios>()
    .HasOne<Location>(s => s.Location)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.LocationId);
```

Comment: How do I do this using the Fluent API? I don't like attributes.

Comment: I understand your distaste for attributes and updated by answer with an API-based solution.

Comment: Thanks. But this requires me to add the complete navigation property. My idea of using just a foreign key property was so I didn't need this :)

Comment: I'm curious why you want to avoid the navigation property. Can you explain?

Comment: Very simple: I don't need it. In my code I don't use this navigation property anywhere. So why add it if you don't use it? But I guess this is a (small) price to pay when using code first with the fluent api :)

Comment: Fair enough :-) I think the way EF works it cannot be avoided to include the navigation property, at least if you would still like to benefit from EF in other terms. Especially the code-first approach needs some kind of reference to the related entitiy. So I guess you are right that you have to pay this price.